# Importing textured psd into blender not showing correct colors in blender

Tags: texturing, uv

Im using blender 2.75a. After I export my uvmap from blender, edit it in photoshop and try to reopen the psd file in blender. I don't see the changes I made in photoshop. Instead I see totally white background and no textures applied on my character. Is there some other way of texturing uv map in blender 2.75a? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though PSD is not presently listed among Blender's [supported image formats](http://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/image_formats.html), it is *partially* supported. Some PSD features will work and some will not.

*Excerpt from [the link Ray Mairlot has provided](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2013-October/059753.html):*

> ## What works:
>
> - 8-bit images (with or without alpha)
> - 16-bit images (alpha discarded)
> - Photoshop files saved with 'Maximum Compatibility'
> - Cycles, Blender internal,  BGE (and player)
>
> ## Known limitations
>
> ## (due to OIIO dependency):
>
> - Images with less than 4 channels show a wrong thumbnail (bug may be in  OIIO)
> - Packed images are not supported
> - We do not write PSD files.

So if you want to be sure your images will work in blender, you can either:

- Export your texture in a fully supported format instead, such as EXR, TIFF, JPEG, or PNG. (If it contains transparency data, use PNG, EXR, or TIFF.)

-OR-

- Stay within to the guidelines of "What Works" to keep your PSD files compatible.

Comment: Well that did import the png file but it doesn't seem to be applying the texture. Anything else I have to do?

Comment: Thanks bro. Got it. I used to nodes to apply my image as a texture.

Comment: Glad it's working for you :-)

Comment: It may not be mentioned as a 'supported image format' but PSDs are supported: http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2013-October/059753.html

Comment: @RayMairlot Hey, thanks for that info! I wonder why it's not listed as a supported format. Maybe it is considered to be *partially* supported?

Comment: Perhaps, or the documentation just isn't up to date.

Comment: @cegaton Done.  :-)

Comment: The thing for me was making sure the psd was in RGB format, not CYMK or something else.