# How do I reveal the "Diffuse and Transparency" option in Cycles Render for Import as plane (png)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, transparency

Currently I can only see the diffuse and emission options. However, on tutorials such as the screenshotted one, it requires that I have other options available. I added the same addons as in the tutorial, and yes, I am in the cycles render engine. 
[image: Tutorial Picture]

---

Here is my screen, currently.
[image: My Screen]

Thank you for all the helps.

Comment: Enable the box that reads **Use Alpha**

Comment: those 2 options were probably removed because they are redundant , the tutorial is using a blender version 2.75,the equivalent of *Diffuse & transparent* is  selecting "Diffuse" and enabling the Alpha Checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Those options are gone.

The way to do transparency is to enable **Use Alpha**

[image]

And then choose between diffuse and emission as the shader.