# Can I see Image Plane Transparency in Viewport OpenGL?

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

I'd like to see my image planes with the correct transparency in the viewport but currently I always see the whole image plane.  Is there a setting that will allow me to see the image "cutout"?[image]

Comment: material view works in Cycles

Comment: Please post the settings you are using for the plane. Do you have "use Alpha" enabled for the image?

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41060/can-blender-use-the-alpha-channel-of-an-image-as-transparency-on-a-plane