# How to map a texture onto an object correctly?

Tags: texturing, uv, objects, uv-image-editor

I want to make a flappy Bird clone for practice and fun but I am struggling with blender and how to use the UV Editor correctly.

The pictures speak for themselves:

[image]

[image]

As you can see I am trying to apply the texture in the picture onto the object. But when I unwrap the object the coordinates get kind of inverted onto the editor on the left. When I rotate my object nothing changes. Also the coordinates on the left do not match the object at all ? I hope you understand what I mean. How can I change the way my object is unwrapped so I can save time trying to map the picture onto the object.

Quick update:
@Duarte Farrajota Ramos
I tried the method in the link you provided and it took me back to step 1: 
[image]

Why is the plane not transparent when I enabled "Use Alpha" everywhere I could in Blender ?

Comment: You don't need all that geometry, a simple plane will suffice.

Comment: I tried to import the texture as a textured plane, but when I render it in my program it is not transparent and I the plane surrounding the texture is black. If you want I can give you a picture

Comment: No need, just use search https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes/

Comment: For something like this it is a lot easier to trace the image in a vector graphics program (like inkscape, illustrator or similar), Once it has been converted to paths (ignoring the background), save it as an svg  file and import that to blender.

Comment: To enable transparency on blender internal read this link: [Can blender use the Alpha channel of an image as transparency on a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41060/can-blender-use-the-alpha-channel-of-an-image-as-transparency-on-a-plane/41064#41064)

Comment: Tried all of it and it didn't work though. I try to render it in eclipse using OpenGl and not in blender btw! I am using "export as Obj file", don't know if it has got anything to do with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Project from view" UV projection is the one you want. Just make sure that first you are viewing the mesh face-on.

Comment: This helped me. I managed it now. Thank you !